# Use Chebyshev inequality to find a least bound for number of purchases in collector's problem

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

From the classic version of this problem, we know $T_N$, the number of purchases required to collect N distinct coupons has $E(T_N) \approx NlogN$; $V(T_N) \approx N^2\pi^2 /6$.

Here I have got a problem asking me to give a least bound on $T_{20}$, such that with probability at least 0.95 I have collected all 20 coupons.

I am clueless with finding bounds on the random variable itself, since I could only write a Chebyshev Inequality on probability. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record, the quantities you have given are approximations/bounds for the expectation and variance; they do not hold with equality. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) has the exact details and also gives a proper application of Chebychev's inequality.

However, if this is a homework question perhaps you are asked to suspend disbelief and assume the expectation and variance are exactly as stated.

Then applying Chebychev can be done as follows:
$$P(T > E[T] + c) \le P(|T - E[T]| > c) \le \frac{V(T)}{c^2}.$$
Plug in your values of $E[T]$ and $V(T)$, and
choose $c$ so that $V(T) / c^2 \le 0.05$. Then the probability that you need more than $E[T]+c$ purchases to get all  coupons is $\le 0.05$; in other words, with $E[T]+c$ purchases you have collected all coupons with probability $\ge 0.95$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I was having some trouble typing $\approx$ so I used =. Regarding this inequality $P(T-ET>c) \leq P(|T-ET|>c)$, is it because we assume the right-tail is less than 0.05 from the question?

Comment: @siegfried That inequality is just saying that the area under the right tail is less than the area under both tails.